# can any one guide me regarding this jquery reg exp validation

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#step1 #fName').focus(function() {
        $('#step1 #fName').keyup(function() {
            var reg = /^([A-Za-z])$/;
            var check = $('#step1 #fName').val();

            if (reg.test(check) == true || check.match(reg) == true) {
                $('#step1 #fName').css('border',' 1px solid #CCC'); 
            }
            else {
                $('#step1 #fName').css('border',' 1px solid #b20000');  
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And I want to apply jQuery validation on this HTML tag:

```
<input type="text" class="width-260" id="fName"/>
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you want to validate? When a user clicks a button? When the form is submitted?

Comment: Tom: I think he would like to change the class of the field, as the user types in data :)

Comment: i want to check on web user key up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a RegExp object, using new RegExp()...

Try with:

```
var reg = new RegExp('^([A-Za-z])$');
```

Comment: Not true: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use literal RegExp creation, however you don't want to assign the `keyup` handler in the `focus` event

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var keyupHandler = function () {
            var self = $(this),
                reg = /^([A-Za-z])$/,
                check = self.val(),
                matches = reg.test(check) || check.match(reg),
                border = matches ? '1px solid #CCC' : '1px solid #b20000';
            self.css('border', border)
        };
    $('#step1 #fName').keyup(keyupHandler).focus();
});​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X3ZDQ/

Also, your current regex only allows one character in the input, If that is not your desired effect, change your regex to `/^([A-Za-z]+)$/`

**UPDATE:**

The problem inherent in "on any alphanumeric" is two-fold.

First, your regex only allows alphas, not numerics.

Second, if you are only validating a single character in your `keyup` event, your validation will generate false positives.

Examples over time:

```
a       //a is valid
an      //n is valid
an1     //1 is not valid, so border changes to red
an1n    //n is valid, so border changes back to grey
```

Final value is `an1n`, which is not valid because it contains a `1`, but your validation routine passes it because the last character typed was an `n`, which is valid.

You are much better off validating the entire string in the input. To do that, change your regex to include a `+` quantifier after your character class:

```
/^([A-Za-z]+)$/
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X3ZDQ/1/

Comment: this is not working :( when user enter his name .. if he/she enter only alpha color stil #ccc. if wrong on any alphanumeric then color change ..

Comment: @GreatOne: What do you mean by "if wrong on any alphanumeric then color change"?

Comment: i m working on keyup function every key want to check is correct reg exp or not if wrong any key then border color change into red other wise still gray.. ithink i can clearify my issue

Comment: @GreatOne: Updated answer to better explain.